# VLANs for Android Devices

Tags: android, networking

Does anyone know of a way I can setup a VLAN for my Android device?  Android comes with the busybox version of `iproute2` so `ip link add ...` isn't allowed, `ip` will claim that `add` is an invalid command.  There's also no copy of `vconfig`.  Does the Android kernel even support VLANs?  If so, what's the easiest way to get a userspace tool for managing VLANs on Android.  I'm on version 2.3.3.

Comment: if you can execute your bin and make system call then try with netlink socket or ioctl. this is what vconfig or iproute2 do internally

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions. This is not a programming question. Non-programming Android questions belong on sites like http://android.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Agree that this is off-topic here. But I'm curious - why are you trying to add a VLAN on an Android device? Is this an Android device with a wired Ethernet port? (if it's WiFi it makes little sense to have VLANs, to me...) What's the use case?

Comment: I'm doing some stuff with USB networking.  It's all taken care of now.  We found an alternative to using a VLAN that worked well for us.

Comment: hi devin, if you found solution to this question or any workaround , could you please share it. I am doing something similar, networking with miniUSB. How exactly you managed to setup VLAN with vconfig? My goal is to receive traffic tagged with VLAN 100 on my android tablet though miniUSB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android 4.0.4 automatically uses the VLAN tag (IEEE_802.1Q) in addition to setting the DiffServ/TOS field in the IP Header.

Older Android Versions (confirmed with 2.2.1 and 2.3.3) seem to disregard these packets - a solution might be to enable VLAN on these older Android versions.